# Using info.plist for storing target-specific values for a multi-target app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, xcodebuild

I have a multi-target iPhone app which currently includes a header file with constant definitions that are conditionally included at build time depending on which target is being built.

However, I was wondering if it might be better to instead include this information in the info.plist for the build, as this generally holds target-specific meta, so logically seems more appropriate.

Therefore, my questions are:

1. Is it acceptable to include custom (non-Apple defined) keys in the info.plist file?
2. Is this a suitable place to include meta for the app which differ between targets?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is acceptable and suitable.

The Info.plist file is preprocessed (must be enabled in project settings by setting Packaging / Preprocess Info.plist File to Yes) by the C pre-processor, so you can have variables (in the form of `${VARIABLE_NAME}`). These variables can be defined in the `User Defined` section in Xcode's target info, making it very easy to switch their value from one target to another.

Comment: Excellent, no idea why I never twigged with Apple's own use of variables but this means my multiple info.plist's could actually be simplified to one and just drop the variables in via the pre-processor during compilation. Makes more sense to me to tweak the drop the settings in at compilation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can set the value in the Get Info pane for your project.

Comment: You can grab that dictionary with `NSDictionary* infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];`