# iphone: get User Defined variable in Target's setting by code?

Tags: iphone, xcode, target, xcconfig

My project have multi-targets. Each target has its own `Class` file for setting stuff. I want to store that `Class` name in a target setting (`Info.plist` or Target's Building setting). So that I can define which class I need to use in each target based on this setting.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989127/using-info-plist-for-storing-target-specific-values-for-a-multi-target-app), I put "a target-specific `User Defined` variable" in each Target's Building Setting.

But don't know how to get it back in my code?

Comment: Which target setting do you mean? The build settings? The Info.plist? Where did you set the variable?

Comment: I put it in the Target's Build Setting.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

As the Info.plist file is preprocessed too, you can use this approach:

Define a User defined setting in your build settings, for Example CLASS_NAME.
And a key to your Info.plist-file. Name the key CLASS_NAME and set the value to `${CLASS_NAME}`.

You can then access this setting by:

```
NSString* className = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] valueForKey:@"CLASS_NAME"];
```

Answer (score 10):

You can not directly use a variable defined in the build settings. These variables are meant to be used by build tools.

Instead define a preprocessor macro in the Preprocessor Macros Variable like 'MYVAR=5'. You can access these macros in your code like:

```
#if MYVAR==5
    //Do something
#endif
```

Please note, that the evaluation of these expressions happens at build-time not at runtime.

It is very typical use to just define a Macro without caring for the value. For example define 'DEBUG=1' in the debug build settings and 'RELEASE=1' in the release build settings.

You can then test using #ifdef or #ifndef

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    // Log
#endif
```

Comment: Oh, I see. How about the Info.plist. Can I store the `Class` name there, and get it from code?

Comment: I have added another answer, for howto use the info.plist.

Comment: If I understand well, there's no way to retrieve the build settings value directly? Because for secrets and keys (that change per configuration) it would be better to not pass through the Plist.